# How to update a row automatically when the time is right?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with 2 columns

```
Time                   Status
2015/3/10 12:00:00       NEW
```

What I want to do is to automatically update the `Status` to "On Going" when the `Time` comes.

How to do that? Thank you!

Comment: You can either [schedule a job for SQL Agent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191439.aspx), or write a windows service in C# and run it periodically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The normal accepted practice would be to run a periodic job (once a minute, once every five minutes, depending on your needs) with an SQL statement like:

```
update mytable
set status = 'ongoing'
where status = 'new'
and time < getdate()
```

Whether you do this with SQL Server Agent, or a scheduled task, or a service is up to you. Given it's really an SQL Server function, I'd probably opt for the first one.